# how can I set this conditions? (Jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, conditional-statements

thanks for your time and first of all I'm a noobie who's been learning by his own javascript so I don't manage quite good the selectors to achieve what I want. Here it's my problem:

html

```
<ul id='stuff' class='goods'>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
<li>list item 3</li>
<li><span class='highlighted'>list item 4</span></li>
<li>list item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id='stuff2' class='goods'>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
<li>list item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.highlighted{
    color: red;
}

.goods{
    border:1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;   
}

.match_group{
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

Look here pelase: * http://jsfiddle.net/nero_noob_123/ctcn7kfy/2/

basically what I want to achieve with the jquery and javascript it's the following.... but I don't know how write it as a condition so try to read it as follows:

```
$('#stuff2').addClass('match_group');

$('#stuff2').addClass('match_group');

if($('li').has('span.highlighted').length){ //so span exist!
        $('span.highlighted').closest('.goods').addClass('match_group');
    }else if($('.goods').hasClass('match_group') && // span.highlight DOESN'T EXIST inside .goods) { 
/// remove the match_group class from '.goods' where span.highlight doesn't exist
    }else{ if any of the '.goods' classes has span.highlighted inside them, don not apply .match_group

    }
```

I hope I have made myself clear, and sorry that's the best I can do with my current knowledge in JQ and javascript

PD: feel free to modify the crapy code I wrote to acheive what I need, thank you!

Comment: Why not just: `$('.goods').has('span.highlighted').addClass('match_group');`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second parameter to `toggleClass` that will turn on or off the specified class. https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

That can be a boolean value, *or* (and this does not appear to be documented) it can be a function returning a boolean result!

```
$('.goods').toggleClass('match_group', function() {return $(this).has("span.highlighted");});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ctcn7kfy/4/